# Laravel Passport between two Laravel projects

Tags: php, laravel, api, access-token, laravel-passport

I Have one big struggle.

I'm trying to create two Laravel websites. One for frontend, and one for backend. The backend will provide API generated information to the frontend. The only one thing that is hard for me is to create the Auth and the Guard for the frontend. There are a lot of tutorials in the web for how to make the system on one Laravel project, but not in two, and on different hostings.

I set the backend by this documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/passport
I test it out and everything looks fine.

The problem is comping with the frontend. I want to get rid of the database authentication and use the passport's tokens :/

Does anyone have some projects or tutorials, that i can look at?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you really done anything? Then show us.

Comment: First of all it is not needed to run two different projects for your requirement.

Comment: That IS the requirement. One project - backend on local machine, and another project - frontend on web hosting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `users(id, created_at, updated_at)` table and a `User` model in frontend

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use App\Models\Helpers\ModelHelper;
use Auth;

class User extends Authenticatable
{        
    //here $userData we will get from backend server

    public static function createAuth($userData){
        $user = new User();
        $user->name = $userData['name'];
        //all other fields

        Auth::login($user);

        return $user;
    }
}
```

After this create a login action in frontend and also create a login at backend server and then create **personal access token** at backend server and return it as json response

Login action at Backend

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    if(Auth::attempt($credentials)){ 
        $user = Auth::user(); 
        $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('MyApp')-> accessToken; 
        $success['user'] = $user;
        return response()->json(['success' => $success], $this-> successStatus); 
    } 
    else{ 
        return response()->json(['error'=>'Unauthorised'], 401); 
    } 
}
```

Frontend Login action

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
      $http = new GuzzleHttp\Client; 

      $response = $http->post('http://backend.local/api/login', [
            'headers' => [
                'Accept' => 'application/json',
            ],
            'form_params' => [
                'email' => 'username@example.vom', 
                'password' => '123', 
            ]
        ]);

        $info = json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);

        $request->session()->put('authUser', $info['success']['user']); 

        \App\User::createAuth($info['success']['user']);

        return redirect('/');
}
```

Create a custom middleware `RemoteAuth`

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;
use Closure;
use Auth;
use App\User;

class RemoteAuth
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!empty(session('authUser'))) {
            $user = $request->session()->get('authUser');

            User::createAuth($user);

            return $next($request);
        }

        return redirect('/login');
    }
}
```

Register this middleware in `Kernel.php` in `protected $routeMiddleware` section.

```
'remoteAuth' => \App\Http\Middleware\RemoteAuth::class
```

Now use this `remoteAuth` middleware in Route

```
Route::middleware('remoteAuth')->get('/test', function (Request $request) { 
    return 'Protected page'; 
});
```

Hope it will give you some idea.

Comment: I did that. But this thing, doesn't make my other routes secure. The middleware guard is not working. Plus this is making some redirect to the server ip address, and i don't want that address can be seen by the user.

Comment: + i read somewhere that the client-id and client-sicret is not something that you want to give to someone. Its not like username and password. Should be like id for the frontend to identify to the backend + check for username and password from the Auth form.

Comment: So i have to install the passport on the frontend too, right?

Comment: do you have login action in backend server ?

Comment: On the Backend only Passport

Comment: I'll try it and tell you after that. But just to be sure... The client_id and client_secret shouldn't they be from from the backend server?

Comment: don't you want to add `client_id` and `client_secret` at front end server ? yes both should  be from backend server

Comment: Yeah, just your comment in the code "//create constant in frontend" confused me a little bit.

Comment: `Client error: POST http://server.local/oauth/token resulted in a 401 Unauthorized response: {"error":"invalid_client","message":"Client authentication failed"}`

The client_id, client_secret, username and password are 100% correct

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179002/discussion-between-rkj-and-nicox).

Comment: ADDITIONAL (For those who have the same problem):
1. The correct code for having the session is: `Auth::guard('api')->attempt($token['success']['user']);` Where `$token['success']['user']` have to return array with the database info for the user from the backend. 2. You have to build login and logout route, because the system will still search for it.

Comment: ADDITIONAL 2: Actually this doesn't work neither... The problem is that i already had some session from way back before, when i tested the regular Auth, and i didn't logged out ... So thats why the guard let me open the route. After i logout i never could login. `Auth::guard('api')->attempt();` Doesn't do much but just check in the frontend users database does the `$token['success']['user']` is the same and returning true or false. :/ Stuck again. Somehow i have to use `Auth::login(...);` but this request need $user->getAuthIdentifier(), which is not in the return request from the backend :/